# useSate doesn't execute in axios promise

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

this is a part of a react component

```
  const listId = props.listId;
  const [list, setList] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    axios.get(`http://localhost:9000/lists/${listId}`).then((res) => {
      if (isMounted) {
        setList({ ...res.data });
      }
    });
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  });
```

for some reason the setList doesn't execute

Comment: Hi, have you verified that the axios call is executed and you get a response?

Comment: yes i get the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this codesandbox, it works fine.

codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-bush-5v3hf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hey, check out the link I mentioned above.